# PayPal Payments Advanced Setup Error

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payflowpro

I am trying to integrate PayPal advanced payments into my website so that users can make payments directly on the website, however I am having trouble with setting it up. This is what my code looks like:

```
$amt = 10.00;
$txt = "Pay Now!";

$PF_HOST_ADDR = "https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com";

$secureTokenId = uniqid('', true);

$postData = "USER=" . "username"
        .   "&VENDOR=" . "username"
        .   "&PARTNER=" . "PayPalCA"
        .   "&PWD=" . "Password"
        .   "&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y"
        .   "&SECURETOKENID=" . $secureTokenId
        .   "&TRXTYPE=S"
        .   "&AMT=" . $amt;


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $PF_HOST_ADDR);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$resp) {echo "<p>To order, please contact us.</p>";}

parse_str($resp, $arr);

if ($arr['RESULT'] != 0) {echo "<p>To order, please contact us.</p>";}

echo "<iframe src='https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com?SECURETOKEN=" . $arr['SECURETOKEN'] . "&SECURETOKENID=" . $secureTokenId . "&MODE=TEST' width='490' height='565' border='0' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowtransparency='true'>";
```

I'm using layout C (embedded iframe) instead of A or B (Hosted checkout pages, which would use a form at the end instead of an iframe).

The result I get looks like this:

```
Array ( [RESULT] => 1 [RESPMSG] => User authentication failed )
```

And the iframe gives the following error:

```
Error: Invalid Merchant or Merchant doesn't exist!
```

I am entering the same information I use to log into my account at https://manager.paypal.com/ and I have done all the required setup on that website. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding and confirming an additional email on the PayPal side, not PayPal Manager? I have heard from a few merchants getting this error message. They resolved it with adding and confirming an extra email on PayPal. If not contacting Payflow support is the best option to confirm the setup of both PayPal and Payflow.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided works fine as long as the manager credentials are working properly.

The only way I was able to get that error with correct credentials is changing from TEST to LIVE inside of the hosted checkout setup page inside the manager account.

You may want to try creating a secondary user in your manager account if those settings are correct.

Comment: Hi, I am entering the same credentials as I use to log into the PayPal Manager website. The hosted checkout pages setup is in TEST mode and I created another user and tried it with the new username, however I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Then this is not a coding problem. I would contact PayPal's PayFlow support to see if there are settings on your manager account that aren't set right.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by logging into the PayPal Manager, going to *Service Settings->Customize* and clicking *Save and Publish*.